# Cannot Downgrade React-Native version from 0.62 to 0.61.4

Tags: react-native, expo

Expo 37 mentions it will work with react-native 0.61.4. When I check my react-native version, it states:

```
$ npm view react-native version
0.62.2
```

I have tried: 1-) Running npm remove react-native, then clearing package-lock.json, then setting react-native version 0.61.4 in package.json, and running npm install again. Tried only npm install react-native@0.61.4 as well.

When I run the verification the result is the same:

```
$ npm view react-native version
0.62.2
```

How can I properly downgrade to react-native 0.61.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm view react-native version` shows the version of current stable `version` is available.

to check local version, just run:

`npm outdated`, this will show your local outdated version or using list `npm list --depth=0` in root directory

Comment: Great, thanks @Muhammad! I thought it was showing my local versions. I ran this command, and local version is ok. There are really some really old outdated though... Thanks again!!